# mongodb getting empty list for collection

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, fastapi

I am using mongodb with fastapi. When I am trying to get all collection I am getting empty list. here is my code:

```
#database.py
client = MongoClient("url")
selldei_db = client["selldei"]
ads_collection = selldei_db["ads"]

#models.py
class Ads(BaseModel):
      ads_title: str
      ads_description: str
      is_published: bool = False

#schameas.py
def ads_serializer(single_ads) -> dict:
    return{
        "ads_title": single_ads["ads_title"],
        "ads_description":single_ads["ads_description"],
        "is_published": single_ads["is_published"]

    }

def ads_list_serializer(ads_list)-> list:
    return [ads_serializer(single_ads) for ad in ads_list]

#my route url for get all collection
@router.get('/all_ads')
def all_ads():
    ads =  ads_list_serializer(ads_collection.find())
    return ads

@router.post('/post_ads/')
   def ads_post(ads:Ads):
   ads = selldei_db.ads_collection.insert_one(dict(ads))
   return {"status":"sucess"}
```

here is screenshot of my databse:

[image]

Comment: Your collection is named `ads_collection` in your screenshot, but `ads` in your code. It doesn't seem like you're querying the collection you think you're querying?

Comment: @MatsLindh also tried `ads_collection` but getting error `NameError: name 'single_ads' is not defined` from my `ads_list_serializer`. I also have post method for ` selldei_db["ads"]` whenever I post somethings it's goes to ads_collection.

Comment: Does the `ads_collection` variable from `database.py` make its way into `schameas.py`?

Comment: yes `ads_collection = selldei_db["ads"]`

Comment: You're trying to access `single_ads` here, but you've named your variable `ads`: `return [ads_serializer(single_ads) for ad in ads_list]`

Comment: (Sorry, you've named it `ad`, not `ads` or `single_ads`)

Comment: @MatsLindh thanks I didn't notice that. Now it's working